# How can I get the ftpsState of all my Azure App Services

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get the ftps state of all of my app services.

I tried the following:

```
az webapp list --query "[].[name,siteConfig.ftpsState]"
```

In the results, the name is populated, but the ftpsState is always null.

Comment: Even I got the same result,all the values are null.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCaqI.png)

Comment: But when I tried for Single App, got the [value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw93D.png).

Comment: You can see the FTPState is disabled by [Azure Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsxuk.png).May be that is the reason the value is displaying as null.

Comment: Refer this blog by [Charbel Nemnom](https://charbelnemnom.com/enable-ftps-on-azure-app-services-with-azure-policy/?expand_article=1) for enabling the FTPState using Azure Policy,then try to retrieve the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the Resource Graph explorer.
Try this query

```
appserviceresources
| project name, properties.FtpsState
```

Comment: This works, but can you tell me how to filter it by properties.FtpsState is not Disabled?

Comment: I figured it out - appserviceresources | project name, properties.FtpsState | where properties_FtpsState != 'Disabled'